# Running a wordpress action when a custom post type term (taxonomy category) is changed

Tags: custom-post-types, actions

Trying to make a system whereby a function is called upon an admin changing the taxonomy category (term - if i understand correcrtly) of a custom post type.

I thought the action tag "edit_category" would do this, but doesnt seem to work:

```
add_action('edit_category_form', 'myFunction');
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'set_object_terms' is probably the hook you want.  It gets passed the following: post_id, terms, term_taxonomy ids, taxonomy, append, old term_taxonomy ids.

You can use the post_id and taxonomy params to determine if its the post type and taxonomy you want to hook into, and then check if term_taxonomy_ids differs from the old term_taxonomy_ids to decide whether anything was changed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
add_action('set_object_terms', 'do_stuff_when_taxo_changes', 10, 1);

function do_stuff_when_taxo_changes($post_id) {

    // Do Stuff

}
```

Comment: I'd use `add_action( 'set_object_terms', 'do_stuff_when_taxo_changes', 10, 6 );`, because that way you'll have access to the full list of parameters.